# React Router - Mobile First: Don't unmount the current component until the new one is ready?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4

**TL;DR:** When transitioning pages with **react-router v4**, how to keep current component until the new component is ready i.e. it made its ajax calls and fetched necessary data to display?

**Currently** react-router v4 works like this:

1. User clicks link
2. Route changes
3. Unmount the current component & mount new matching component
4. Ajax calls made to fill components data

However if we think of **mobile-first approach**, the workflow should be:

1. User clicks link
2. matching component is mounted, hidden, being initialised via its ajax calls in componentDidMount/updated
3. initialisation done, component and its data are ready
4. Change URL, unmount the old component and display the new one.

Changing URL could be after user clicks the link or after the new component is ready.

By using **redux** we can achieve this by:

1. Make all components stateful, have componentXLoad() actions for each
2. Instead of route change, fire these actions and inside the actions change the url **after** the component's data is fetched

However, I believe we do not need to go all the way and make every component stateful and generate lots of actions for every page transition.

Idea I have was:

1. User clicks the link
2. Route changes, new component is being initialised
3. If new component's render() method returns null, don't unmount the current component
4. When new component is ready, rendering non-null, unmount the old component and display the new one.

I believe this is theoretically possible.

Is there already a library doing this?
Or is this something easy to do with React Router v4's API?

Also:
What are the implications on this on SEO, any chance Google considers as cloaking to penalise the site?

I've found this library https://github.com/faceyspacey/redux-first-router, seems it can do this by making everything stateful, but again for something this simple seems like an overkill to switch to that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you need it only for this specific case I'd say try this:

1. From component A fetch the data you need to fetch (maybe show some indicator while fetching)
2. Transition to component B passing the data as custom props
3. Component B renders initially with the data

Comment: Is fetching next components data in current component a good practice?

Comment: "Good practice" and "exceptional case" do not go hand in hand